# Turkey e-Visa requirements

Tags: indian-citizens, turkey, e-visas

I am an Indian Passport holder residing in Sweden and hold Sweden Resident Permit. I am planning to visit Turkey between 31 May-June 7 2023 and looking to apply for e-Visa.

My passport is valid for the next 10 years and my current Sweden Resident Permit expires on 30 June 2023 but the renewal of the Sweden Resident Permit is in progress.

I would like to check if I am eligible to apply for e-Visa or will there be any challenegs since my current Sweden resident permit expires on June 30 2023 and I may not receive the NEW Sweden resident permit before my travel to Turkey.

Note I will exit Turkey on June 7 2023 well before my Sweden Resident Permit expiry date.

Can I go on and apply for e-visa? I am just confused with this statement in the e-visa requirements as my resident permit expires in a month.

**Those who do not have a passport or passport substitute document with a validity of at least 60 days from the end of the date visa validity period will not be allowed to enter Turkey**

Answer (score 2):

A Swedish Resident Permit is neither a passport, nor a passport substitute. Your Indian passport is a passport. You can certainly apply for a Turkish eVisa.

(The Turkish government eVisa ["Who is Eligible" FAQ webpage](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/who-is-eligible-for-e-visa/) lists countries whose citizens can obtain eVisas, and India is not included. However, I just tried an application entering "India" as my country of citizenship and the eVisa application was approved. I didn't continue and pay for it; my application might have derailed had I proceeded further.)

The real problem, however, is this: the airline will not permit you to board a flight to return to Sweden if, at the time of flight departure, you are not holding a valid Swedish Resident Permit. Holding only an Indian passport with no valid Swedish Resident Permit, the airline will conclude you will not be able to enter Sweden. They will therefore refuse to carry you even if you have a flight reservation.

Under these circumstances, you should reschedule your trip, and not depart Sweden until you have a renewed and valid Swedish Resident Permit in your possession.

Comment: Thanks, this really helps. It’s only a week travel and I will be returning to Sweden before my Sweden resident permit expires. I will be returning back on 8th June whereas my Sweden permit is valid until 30th June.

Comment: Schengen visas and RPs are valid to get a TR evisa for most visa countries [MFA](https://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa)